# Integration via uSubstitution

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm having trouble with the following question.

$\int_{0}^{\pi/6} {{2+ cos^2(x)} \over cos^2(x)} dx$

This is what I have so far , sorry about the png , I'd type it out but studying more is more important right now x)

[image]

Comment: **Hint** Split up the integrand and rewrite it as $2\sec^2 x + 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Concerning your computation, you have made a mistake : $du=sin(x)dx$ does not imply that $arcsin(x)du=dx$ but instead

$$dx=du/sin(x)=du/\sqrt{1-\cos(x)^2}=du/\sqrt{1-u^2}$$

But $\dfrac{2+u^2}{u^2(\sqrt{1-u^2})}$ is not easy to manipulate...

2) Instead, there is more direct way to obtain the result ; when splitting the integrand you discover at once a primitive function :

$$\int_0^{\pi/6}\left(\dfrac{2}{\cos(x)^2}+1\right)dx=[2\tan(x)+x]_0^{\pi/6}$$

$$=2/\sqrt{3}+\pi/6$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, you made several mistakes in your attempt like the derivative of $\cos(x)$ is missing a minus sign, the $\arcsin(x)$ transformation and so on...actually your whole substitution is quite off.

Here is how I would go about it:

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/6} {{2+ \cos^2(x)} \over \cos^2(x)} dx=&\int_{0}^{\pi/6} {{2} \over \cos^2(x)} dx+\int_{0}^{\pi/6} 1dx\\
=&2\int_{0}^{\pi/6} {{1} \over \cos^2(x)} dx+\frac \pi 6
\end{align}
so now let's tackle the first integral and we get
\begin{align}
2\int_{0}^{\pi/6} {{1} \over \cos^2(x)} dx=2\int_{0}^{\pi/6} {{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)} \over \cos^2(x)} dx=&2\int_{0}^{\pi/6} (1+\tan^2(x))dx\\
=&2[\tan(x)|_{0}^{pi/6}]=2\tan(\pi/6)=\frac 2 {\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}
by using the fact, that $\tan(x)'=1+\tan^2(x)$. You can solve the last integral also by substitution ($u=\tan(x)$, then apply a short transformation and use polynomial division etc.).

All in all we get 
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/6} {{2+ \cos^2(x)} \over \cos^2(x)} dx=\frac \pi 6+\frac 2 {\sqrt{3}}
$$

Comment: A little remark concerning the initial remark: there is - truly speaking - no "final" error in the fact that the minus sign has been omitted because it is a jacobian computation which has to be considered in absolute value

Comment: @JeanMarie I am not so sure about that...I get what you mean that in higher dimensions you have the absolute value of the determinant, but in 1-dimension you cannot omit the sign and therefore the orientation

Comment: I partly agree, because simultaneously, the bounds of integration are switched. But there is no reason for a "singularity" in 1 dimension...

Comment: I partly agree as well, the switch of the integration bounds does not always compensate, consider to integrate $\sin(x)\cos(x)$ from $\pi$ to $3/2\pi$ by substituting $u=\cos(x)$, if you drop the sign,you'll get $-1/2$, correct would be $1/2$